# copy object behind shared pointer containing a list of shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, deep-copy

I have a `shared_ptr<Tree> tree` and a `shared_ptr<TreeNode> node` that contains a list of childrens as shared pointers.

```
class TreeNode
{
protected:
    std::weak_ptr<TreeNode> parent;

    /**
    A list containing the children of this node
    */
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeEdge>>> children;

   ...
```

A Tree needs only to be given a TreeNode as its root.

```
Tree::Tree(const shared_ptr<TreeNode> root)
    : root(root)
{}
```

So to create that sub Tree I try to get a TreeNode and call the Tree constructor with it.

```
shared_ptr<TreeNode> treeNode = oldTree->getASpecialNode();
shared_ptr<Tree> newTree = make_shared<Tree>(treeNode);
```

Now the root of `newTree` is `treeNode`. But the problem is, every TreeNode is pointing to its parent. So does `treeNode`.

```
weak_ptr<TreeNode> TreeNode::getParent() const
{
    return parent;
}
```

When calculating the root by going through the parents of any TreeNode in `newTree`, we will reach a different root node than `newTreeNode`, because `newTreeNode` itself has a parent.

Deleting that parent is no solution, because the object is shared and we will need it in the original Tree. So the only solution I see is to copy the TreeNode and copy all it's members.

How can I do that?

Based on other answers on SO I tried this:

```
std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> TreeNode::clone() const
{
    auto clone = new TreeNode (*this );
    clone->setParent(weak_ptr<TreeNode>());
    return shared_ptr<TreeNode>(clone);
}
```

But still calculating the parents will lead to the original root node. So I wasn't able to create a sub tree.

I have the feeling that it's wrong to use `shared_ptr` for `Tree` and `TreeNode`, but it's not my code. I just need to add a feature.

Comment: Your clone should do a deep copy: create a new node, and clone each child.

Comment: Since your title includes the word "copy" the answers you have so far quite reasonably assume you want a copy. In other cases Sub tree could also refer to a tree made up of some of the existing nodes (like a filtered version of the existing tree). That kind of subtree would benefit from the shared pointer to the vector of children. So that's a reason for it to use shared pointer, but if that's not a requirement, then I'd agree that the shared_ptrs do look odd.

Comment: I think I'd prefer that kind of subtree. But I'd have a problem with the parent thing. Somewhere in the code nodes need to be traversed through the parents. Then one would go up to the original root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire subtree has to be cloned, not just the sub-root. Since none of the pointers are copied, it is not useful to copy initialize the clone. Also, you should avoid bare pointers to allocated memory in order to guarantee strong exception safety.

Untested example:

```
std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> TreeNode::clone() const
{
    auto clone = std::make_shared<TreeNode>();
    clone->children->reserve(children->size());
    for(const auto& c : *children) {
        auto c_clone = c->clone();
        c_clone->setParent(clone);
        clone->children->push_back(c_clone);
    }
    return clone;
}
```

---

> I have the feeling that it's wrong to use `shared_ptr` for `Tree` and `TreeNode`

I *share* your feeling. Certainly when the nodes have a parent pointer, it is unclear how the nodes could be sensibly shared across multiple trees.

`std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeEdge>>>` also seems excessive indirection.

Comment: You forget to set parent of the new children.

Answer (score 0):

Your clone function should look like something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> TreeNode::clone() const
{
    auto res = std::make_shared<TreeNode>();

    for (auto child : *children) {
        res->AddChild(child->clone());
    }
    return res;
}
```